# Почему получаю такую ошибку Instance member 'backgroundGreyColor' cannot be used on type 'UIColor'

Tags: xcode, swift

Я сделал себе такое расширение которое дает нужный цвет по его hex коду и в этом же расширении определил цвет который хочу использовать, но получаю вот такую ошибку

```
Instance member 'backgroundGreyColor' cannot be used on type 'UIColor'
```

Вот код расширения

---

```
extension UIColor {
convenience init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) {
    assert(red >= 0 && red <= 255, "Invalid red component")
    assert(green >= 0 && green <= 255, "Invalid green component")
    assert(blue >= 0 && blue <= 255, "Invalid blue component")

    self.init(red: CGFloat(red) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(green) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}

convenience init(netHex: Int) {
    self.init(red: (netHex >> 16) & 0xff, green: (netHex >> 8) & 0xff, blue: netHex & 0xff)
}

var backgroundGreyColor: UIColor {
    get {
        return UIColor(netHex: 0x262626)
    }
}
```

---

вот так обращаюсь к этой переменной

```
let backgroundGreyColor = UIColor.backgroundGreyColor.cgColor
```

И получаю ошибку...

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так в ошибке же все, собственно и описано. `backgroundGreyColor` должен быть вызван от объекта класса:

```
let backgroundGreyColor = UIColor().backgroundGreyColor.cgColor
```

Ну либо сделайте ее статической:

```
static var backgroundGreyColor: UIColor {...
```